# How to 'Name' a BitmapImage

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

For debugging purposes I'd like to set a `BitmapImage`'s `Name` property. Unfortunately it doesn't exit. Is there any way to identify a specific `BitmapImage` when setting a breakpoint? In Winforms, *all* Controls have a [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name(v=vs.110).aspx) property, and even if they didn't, we could use the [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property. For [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx), on the other hand, I can't find anything comparable.

**To clarify**: I need something defining the `BitmapImage` itself, not the variable pointing to it, so that if I have `bi2 = bi1` - I can check if `bi2` is this `BitmapImage`.

Comment: Seems there just isn't such property, or any other property you can use for debugging purposes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to compare the pixel data of two bitmaps to see if they are the same picture?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x:Name` to define a name of any object in XAML. Then you can use it for example for the debugging purposes.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage x:Name="MyBitmapImage"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help - see my clarification to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand what you're trying to achieve, but can't you just use the Image.Source property? Of course you'll need to cast it if you want to access it as BitmapImage...